# Top tabbed navigation in Wix's react native navigation

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm trying to implement top tabbed navigation on a screen. The screen isn't set to root and is navigated to from a button click. This is how I'm doing it:

```
Navigation.push(this.props.containerId, {
  topTabs: [
    {
      name: "myApp.UserDetails",
      navigationOptions: {
        topTab: {
          title: "Tab 1"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      name: "myApp.UserMedicalDetails",
      navigationOptions: {
        topTab: {
          title: "Tab 2"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

The application neither crashes on the button click nor it navigates to the new screen but it gives the following warning:

[image]